# How does AngularJS do what it does (what makes it tick)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm looking at AngularJS, trying to learn the basics. Quite experienced with JavaScript and server programming, HTTP etc, so I do have an understanding of what it does. I'm watching Curran Keller's "50 examples" tutorial on YouTube (link below), and I've found lots of documentation on *what* Angular does... but not so much on *how* it does it. Knowing the rough on how Angular is able to do all these neat things -- it being "only" a JavaScript wrapper, executing in the web browser -- would be helpful when I am to write my first Angular "app" (webpage with metadata-enhanced JS, as I currently think of it). ;-) that ought to get the discussion going!

### So, here's what I think I've gleaned so far:

Angular JS *is* JavaScript. It runs in the browser, via a .js file, so eventually the directives and tags and "angular code" (controller) is translated into JavaScript, which is what's actually run in the browser.

As such, Angular is really "just" a library of wrappers for normal JavaScript objects. I guess this is the main point; it's a simplification of the otherwise rather complex "native" JavaScript code. For example, rather than instantiating an `XMLHttpRequest` object, and using it to GET or POST some data to/from a server, Angular provides an $http service. All you need to type is `$http.get();`

Furthermore, Angular has this powerful dynamic propagation of changes in the UI, as the user uses the page. Almost like in Excel, if a piece of data is changed somewhere, then all other usages/references of same data (i.e. a variable, an HTML form element, or just a variable output to HTML with `{{myVariable}}`) are updated accordingly. Automatically, and immediately.

Another cool property is enhancing HTML tags with Angular directives. This is a very simple way of dynamically producing HTML output (or just plain text) from what ever is in the Angular (i.e. JavaScript) memory. Again, this can be done with plain vanilla JS, traversing the DOM and inserting child elements, but Angular alleviates the need for any of that complex coding. All you need to program is `<li ng-repeat="name in names">{{name}}</li>`

So, how does Angular achieve all this, using "only" JavaScript? Obviously, as with `GetElementById`, JavaScript can access (read) and parse the HTML DOM, so I take it Angular begins by reading in the entire document and looking for any HTML tags with the `ng-app` directive. These are parsed further, and Angular code is converted to either generate additional HTML output (e.g. `ng-repeat`), or translated into embedded JavaScript (as in `$scope.name='';`).

One thing I've had trouble finding an answer to in the documentation, is what the dollar signs do. I *think* I know the answer, but I'm not confident. Since Angular has its own JavaScript-like programming language, Angular needs to be able to discern between the JavaScript-parts (e.g. variables used in HTML FORM elements) and the Angular objects. I mean, what's Angular function calls and what's the input/arguments to those. Prepending $ to the Angular words lets the Angular JS-translator know what not to translate, so to speak?

**Maybe someone can follow up on this, correct me where I'm wrong?**

The examples in Curran Keller's "Introduction to Angular.js in 50 Examples" (http://youtu.be/TRrL5j3MIvo) is a great reference. For instance, maybe the dollowing simple example could be a starting point? In this example, I'm wondering (in addition to the above thoughts) what specifically is the purpose of the `$scope` object. Can we rename it to $whatever, or is "scope" a reserved word?

```
<html ng-app="nameApp">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Angular.js Example 14</title>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.1/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      var nameApp = angular.module('nameApp', []);
      nameApp.controller('NameCtrl', function ($scope) {
        $scope.names = ['Larry', 'Curly', 'Moe'];
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body ng-controller="NameCtrl">
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="name in names">{{name}}</li>
    </ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: How about taking a look at the Angular.js source code itself (https://github.com/angular/angular.js/tree/master/src) or running code through a JavaScript debugger?

Comment: as for your last question `$scope` is a dependency and you can not name it whatever you want,  the `$scope` service is registered by the `$provide` service as an injectable dependency and is injected by the `$injector` service, it works just the same as if you would write your own service, only `$scope` comes pre-packaged with angular. As to finding out how Angular does what it does I'd recommend reading a good book about it: I read http://www.apress.com/9781430264484 and although it doesn't go very deep into the details I felt like I learned a lot from it

Comment: Angular is JavaScript. Its a JavaScript framework. Like flask and django are python frameworks. Why do you keep referring to "only" and "just" JavaScript. If you want to know more, about how it does what it does, look at the source code. Stackoverflow isn a site for discussions. Its a Q&A site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> One thing I've had trouble finding an answer to in the documentation, is what the dollar signs do.

The dollar signs are simply a naming convention reserved for Angular and JQuery. It's simply for readability to quickly discern what is Angular/JQuery functions. See http://google.github.io/styleguide/angularjs-google-style.html#dollarsign.

> In this example, I'm wondering (in addition to the above thoughts) what specifically is the purpose of the $scope object. Can we rename it to $whatever, or is "scope" a reserved word?

$scope is special, it refers to the application model. See docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope and docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller (can't post direct links because I don't have the reputation yet :( ).

In the above example, $scope is used to communicate between the controller and the DOM. The DOM can only refer to items on the scope in angular bindings. Breaking down the example above:

```
<body ng-controller="NameCtrl">
```

This instantiates the controller named NameCtrl, and sets up the same $scope between the DOM and that instance of NameCtrl. This element and all children elements can now reference the same $scope as NameCtrl.

```
$scope.names = ['Larry', 'Curly', 'Moe'];
```

This is where the controller is setting the model to Larry/Curly/Moe for the DOM to consume.

```
<li ng-repeat="name in names">{{name}}</li>
```

"names" refers to the same $scope.names in NameCtrl (remember, you don't write $scope from the DOM). Whenever the controller NameCtrl updates $scope.names, the DOM will update as well, creating a list item for each element in the array 'names', and each element has it's own $scope as well.

I suggest going through some of the AngularJS tutorial app helps quite a bit: docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/